# How to create Sphinx role which automatically creates a label for references?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

In my documentation, I often refer to XML tags. So I try to write a small extension to simplify adding and referencing tags to the documentation. The documentation shall look like this:

```
My text, referencing to :xmltag-ref:`ExampleTag` here.

The :xmltag:`ExampleTag` Explained in Detail
--------------------------------------------

This section describes the tag...
```

I wrote a simple extension like this:

```py
import re
from docutils import nodes

def xmltag(name, rawtext, text, lineno, inliner, options={}, content=[]):
    literal_node = nodes.literal(text=text, classes=['xmltag'])
    # <--- HERE: How to add target?
    result_nodes = [literal_node]
    return result_nodes, []

def xmltag_ref(name, rawtext, text, lineno, inliner, options={}, content=[]):
    source = f'tag-{text}'
    reference_node = nodes.reference(classes=['xmltag-ref'], text=text)
    reference_node['refid'] = source
    result_nodes = [reference_node]
    return result_nodes, []

def setup(app):
    app.add_role("xmltag-ref", xmltag_ref)
    app.add_role("xmltag", xmltag)

    return {
        'version': '1.0',
        'parallel_read_safe': True,
        'parallel_write_safe': True,
    }
```

If I add a reference manually, everything works as expected, but I could not find a way how to add a label automatically if the Tag is defined in a title.

I like how the automatic reference works, e.g. using the `option` directive:

```
.. option:: --example

    text...
```

This automatically creates a label, which can be referenced using `:option:'--example'`. I would like to have something similar, but with the flexibility to use it in a title, which also creates an entry in the TOC.

**How can I add a label in a role element?**

*Or, is there another way, how this should be solved correctly?*